# data install/upgrade not creating category attribute

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, installdata

i'm trying to add an attribute to the categories, but my setup doesn't add anything
the input is visible in the categories, but you even on save the input value stays empty
and i can't find any reference to my attribute in database (plus i would like it to be an integer)

here my code
UpgradeData.php

```
<?php
namespace Cursol\CategoryAttribute\Setup;


use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface,
UpgradeDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{


    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }




    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'origine_attribute_id', [
            'type'     => 'text',
            'label'    => 'Origin Attribute Id',
            'input'    => 'text',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '0',
            'required' => false,    
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'Display Settings',
        ]);
        }


}
```

category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="origine_attribute_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Origin Attribute Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you compare with my code this code is working for me and my attribute show in general information

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddOrigineAttributeIdCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'origine_attribute_id',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'origine_attribute_id',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'origine_attribute_id');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```

category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="origine_attribute_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">origine_attribute_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It shoes up in generalinformation, but when i save it, the value stays empty

Comment: @user80390 you can check enable developer mode and log files check

Comment: i'm already in developer mode, bu i've got nothing related in the logs, no erros, nothing except the cache invalidation for the saved category

Comment: i've also tried it on a clean install (magento 2.4) with the same result, it shows up in general setting empy, and i can't save any value

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need to add it to an attribute group:

```
$attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getAttributeSetId(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE);
$attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->setAttributeGroupId(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $attributeSetId);
$eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(CategoryAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'origine_attribute_id');
```